# Alerta ao tentar usar Drawer Navigation

Tags: react-navigation

Peço que os amigos tentem fazer o seguinte.

Iniciem um projeto React Native (aqui estou usando a versão 0.64.1), instalem as dependências sugeridas para o uso do React Navigation (aqui estou usando a versão 5.9.4) (fonte https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started)

```
npm install @react-navigation/native
npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

Feito isso, instalem a dependência do drawer e reproduzam o exemplo do Drawer Navigation em https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation.

```
npm install @react-navigation/drawer

import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
        title="Go to notifications"
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function NotificationsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Go back home" />
    </View>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Aqui funciona perfeito, MAS sempre recebo o seguinte WARN "If you want to use Reanimated 2 then go through our installation steps".

Bem, como podem ver nesse exemplo, não uso o Reanimated 2, no máximo instalo o react-native-reanimated conforme sugerido pela documentação.

Então porque o alerta? Tudo funciona normal, mas é chato recebermos um alerta e não saber a razão. Também ocorre com vocês? Já repararam nisso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O fato é que alguns pacotes do React Navigation utilizam o React Reanimated, como o Drawer e o Material Top Tabs.

"Reanimated 2 é construído principalmente em C ++ usando a infraestrutura de Módulos Turbo que ainda não foi completamente implantada no React Native (especificamente no Android) Por isso, **a instalação do novo Reanimated requer etapas adicionais além de apenas adicionar uma dependência ao package.json**." Fonte: "https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/installation/"

Na fonte citada acima também vem o passo a passo dessas etapas adicionais. Feito isso finalmente o alerta parou!!!